# How to restore handling of percent-encoded org links?

Tags: org-mode

I have two machines with synchronized org files. One runs Emacs 27.2/Org mode 9.4.4, the other 24.3/7.9.3f. I have noticed that org links created on the older Emacs version encode spaces as %20 while the other doesn't. Org mode 9.4.4 no longer recognizes %20 as space and return error every time I try to open such link.

Is there an option to restore that beaviour for newer Emacs version, so it can again recognize %20 as spaces? Or for the older version to not encode the links when editting them with C-c C-l?

Comment: I can't replicate this under Org 9.5.1 and Emacs 27.1. I just tried using a link with %20 (replacing a "+" with "%20", to be precise) and it worked. I think the problem may be somewhere else, but just to be sure, could you add to your question a very simple example Org link that triggers the problem for you?